# Ajax + Knockout stopBinding tag issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a code like this:

page 1:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <a href="javascript:loadPage()">Test</a>
     <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

page 2:

```
<!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
<div id="testView_content">
     <span data-bind="text: mae"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

relevant js:

```
var lou;

function loadPage() {
    $('#content').html("");
    $.ajax({
        url: "./page/page2.html"
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
        fillPage();
        }
    });

}

function fillPage() {
    $('#content').html(data);
    $('#content').show("slow");


    if (!lou) {
        lou = new Lou();
        ko.applyBindings(lou, document.getElementById('testView_content'));
    }
}
```

KO model:

```
var Lou = function() {

this.mae = ko.observable("test");

};
```

Well, it works on the first time, but if i run the function again, the html will render empty (but the Knockout Model View isnt, i checked). Anyone have any idea? Maybe im doing something wrong using ajax + stopBinding, maybe my load design? I tried using the stopBinding tag wrapping the content div (page 1), instead of creating a new one in page 2, but no success =(.

Im really new to Knockout, so any help would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't looked at the ko yet, but it strikes me that you're not passing the `data` variable to fillPage(), so in line 1 of fillPage(), `data` will equal `undefined` -- unless you've omitted something pertinent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think may be the problem is when you execute the method the second time, the data loaded via ajax is not bind to the model and because the variable 'lou' is now defined will not enter in the if block where you call ko.applyBindings.

I suggest to move the call ko.applyBindings out and after the if block.

```
function fillPage() {
    $('#content').html(data);
    $('#content').show("slow");

    if (!lou) {
        lou = new Lou();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(lou,
        document.getElementById('testView_content'));
}
```